# Facebook sdk breaks update in Progress Bar

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, sdk

Small summary about the app:
You take care of a pet. The user has a swipe menu on the bottom, where on the first view you have 3 progress bars (hunger, play, hygene), the second view are 3 buttons to feed, play or was them. The third view is a store and options button.

When adding the Facebook SDK to my Eclipse project, through Properties > Android, my Progress Bar do not update anymore when the user clicks on the buttons.

The buttons are declared in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void onFoodClick(View v) {
    myPet.setHunger(10, true);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and when clicked they refer to the `PetClass.java` in the pets package:

```
public void setHunger(int amt, boolean up)
{
    if (up)
    {
        this.hunger += amt;
    }
    else{
        this.hunger -= amt;
    }
}
```

This the XML file for MainActivity: http://pastebin.com/7AtDPs9p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in a class which called the layout where the progress bars are located. The call layout was hardcoded and not declared as R.id.layout.

Never hard code! I learned the hard way.